# App creating files while iPhone is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, data-protection

I am struggling with this issue.

My app need to create, while in background, some file. It creates a temporary file (in the temporary folder), then creates a folder inside /Documents, with some files in it.

When my application is compiled in debug, it works. When I compile it in release, and only when passcode is activated, only the first set of files gets created. The second set sees only the creation of the folder inside Documents, but no file can be created, nor in temporary folder nor in Documents/newcreatedfolder.

**This happens only when the application is compiled in release, and with the pass code on.**

I guess it has to do with data protection and the impossibility to create new files while the phone is locked. Is there some entitlement that can give my application the possibility to create and write to new files while in background and locked?

Comment: After you ask for background processing time you only have 3 minutes of run time in the background before you get suspended. (Still in memory but no longer getting processing time.) After that you can be silently terminated at any time without further warning. Are you positive that you are creating your files within that time limit?

Comment: yes, actually the app is running with background mode permissions. I found the solution, and will post it as soon as I have tested it a bit.

Comment: Which background mode permissions? Background sound play? That only lets you run continuously from the background if you are actually playing a sound continuously. Otherwise your background task still expires after 3 minutes.

Comment: gps always permission, so the app could run indefinitely

Comment: And are you calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`?

Answer (score 4):

Files are locked by standard iOS file protection policy, so after the phone is locked all files are encrypted. My solution was this, since I don't need security on those files:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey:NSFileProtectionNone} ofItemAtPath:[GlobalProvider tmpFolder] error:NULL];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey:NSFileProtectionNone} ofItemAtPath:[GlobalProvider documentsFolder] error:NULL];
```

Comment: The syntax `@{NSFileProtectionKey:NSFileProtectionNone}` is a whole lot more concise than `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionNone forKey:NSFileProtectionKey]` and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @DuncanC I updated my answer with your clever use of NSDictionary literals ;)